# Joining 3 tables with Mysql Return Extra Data

Tags: mysql, left-join, join

I have 3 tables - Members, Active, New

Members table:

```
+--------+---------+------------+
| userid | adminid | logindate  | 
+--------+---------+------------+
| test6  | test3   | 03/04/2016 |
| test7  | test3   |            |
+--------+---------+------------+
```

Active table:

```
+----+--------+---------+---------+
| id | userid | adminid | city    |
+----+--------+---------+---------+
| 1  | test6  | test3   | Chicago |
+----+--------+---------+---------+
```

New table:

```
+----+--------+----------+
| id | userid | city     |
+----+--------+----------+
| 1  | test7  | New York |
+----+--------+----------+
```

I want to find out all the members that belong to an Admin ID (test3), whether they are active or new.  The mysql code:

```
    SELECT active.id, active.userid, active.city, members.logindate,
 new.id as a, new.userid as b, new.city as c 
    FROM members
    LEFT JOIN active
    ON members.adminid = active.adminid
    LEFT JOIN new
    ON members.userid = new.userid
    WHERE members.adminid = 'test3'
```

What I expect would be 2 rows of records:

```
+----+--------+---------+------------+---+-------+----------+
| id | userid | city    | logindate  | a |  b    | c        |
+----+--------+---------+------------+---+-------+----------+
| 1  |test6   | Chicago | 03/04/2016 |   |       |          |
+----+--------+---------+------------+---+-------+----------+
|    |        |         |            | 1 | test7 | New York |
+----+--------+---------+------------+---+-------+----------+
```

Instead I got:

```
+----+--------+---------+------------+---+-------+----------+
| id | userid | city    | logindate  | a |  b    | c        |
+----+--------+---------+------------+---+-------+----------+
| 1  |test6   | Chicago | 03/04/2016 |   |       |          |
+----+--------+---------+------------+---+-------+----------+
| 1  |test6   | Chicago |            | 1 | test7 | New York |
+----+--------+---------+------------+---+-------+----------+
```

The data from the first row (from Active table) was repeated in the second row.  What am I doing wrong? Your help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `join` on the `userid` instead of the `adminid`:

```
SELECT active.id, active.userid, active.city, members.logindate,
     new.id as a, new.userid as b, new.city as c 
FROM members
    LEFT JOIN active
        ON members.userid = active.userid
    LEFT JOIN new
        ON members.userid = new.userid
WHERE members.adminid = 'test3'
```

- [Condensed Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71c97/1)